# using cypher to find nodes in a subgraph that are NOT connected to a specified node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, recommendation-engine

I'm learning cypher with Neo4j but I'm having some problems that show I still don't quite get it.

I'm trying to write a query that finds a subgraph and then excludes nodes from that subgraph that are connected to a specified node.

In practice, it's a recommendation problem: I find a set of recommendations, but want to exclude those things that a target use already knows about.

I thought I could do something like:

```
match (u:User{id:"some id"}), (:Category{title:"some category"})-[:categorizes]->(i:Item) 
where not (u)-[:knows_about]-(i) 
return  i
```

but this doesn't work.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong/what I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
MATCH (:Category{title:"some category"})-[:categorizes]->(i:Item)
MATCH (u:User {id:some_id})
WHERE  not (u)-[:knows_about]-(i) 
RETURN i
```

You might want to add a direction in the second WHERE clause (performance!).

Comment: Nope, that doesn't give the expected result. It's still returning items that the user 'knows_about' :-(

Comment: I take that back, it turns out I needed a better understanding of my data :-) I reorganised the above answer into a form which seems a bit more readable: `MATCH (u:User{id:"some id"}) WITH u MATCH (i:Item)<-[:categorizes]-(:Category{title:"some category"}) WHERE NOT (u)-[:knows_about]->(i) RETURN i`

Comment: In fact, don't need the `WITH`, looks like my original query works fine and I just misunderstood what the 'correct' result would look like.

Comment: Looks like I get the best performance with: `MATCH (:Category{title:"some category"})-[:categorizes]->(i:Item) MATCH (u:User{id:"some id"}) WHERE NOT (u)-[:konws_about]->(i) RETURN i`

Comment: Updated my answer. I was unaware of the fact that you could refer to the id like `{id:some_id}`. Feel free to accept. ;-)